# How to remove the only user from windows 10

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, reset

I tested a laptop, and giving it back now, but I wanted to remove my used before doing that. However, since it is the only user on this laptop, I do not get any buttons like "remove this user". Maybe there's some warm reset option that removes all users and on the start the laptop behaves like it just was started?

Comment: @llya - Use the built-in Administrator account

Answer (score 1):

You can do a reset (good to do) that will leave you without a user profile. I suggest doing this.

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with the option to Keep Nothing. Be sure to change the options to keep nothing. That will reset your computer and ensure nothing of yours is left behind.